# Attempting to scrape schools that have offered football players a scholarship, but encountering issues

Tags: python, selenium

I've been attempting to scrape the schools that have offered scholarships to high school football players on Rivals but I've been running into some issues.

Here is an example page: https://n.rivals.com/content/prospects/2021/de-javion-stepney-235539#school-interests

I've been able to scrape the names of all the schools once the table is extended, but I want to only scrape the schools that have the school offer checkmark in the same row as the school. How would I do that?

Additionally, although I'm able to scrape the school names, it frequently will repeat random rows before going to the next player page and I can't figure out why.

Here is what I have so far:

```py
Offered_By_List = []

for s in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('school-logo-name'):
    Offered_By_List.append(s)
```

Any help would be appreciated, been stuck on this for a bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ancestor`, this is just to scrape the school names:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="checkmark ng-scope"]//ancestor::tr//div[@class="school-logo-name"]')
```

But if you want to scrape all data each rows, just remove `//div[@class="school-logo-name"]` in the above xpath.

Answer (score 1):

you can use xpaths to implement a relationship between checkmarks and row in the table, below xpath sample from your example will fetch the row which has checkmark. you will notice that this xpath has selected only those rows which has checkmarks (15 in this page). Then save this as an array and iterate through all the rows and saving school name.

```
//tbody/tr[td[5]/div[@class="checkmark ng-scope"]]
```

[image]

Or directly use below code

```
list = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody/tr[td[5]/div[@class="checkmark ng-scope"]]/td[1]/div/*[@class="ng-binding ng-scope"]")
for s in list:
   print(s.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use Selenium here as the data is returned within the html as valid json in the element attributes. There's a few ways to pull out the school names, but I did it with pandas as you can get it into tables as well, and if you want more data than just the school names, you can manipulate it how you'd like. I also grabbed the player profile as well:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://n.rivals.com/content/prospects/2021/de-javion-stepney-235539#school-interests'


response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

jsonStr = soup.find('rv-user-forecast-banner')['prospect']
playerData = json.loads(jsonStr)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(playerData)
print (df1)



jsonStr = soup.find('rv-prospect-school-interests')['data']
schoolIntData = json.loads(jsonStr)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(schoolIntData)
print (df2)

schoolsOffered = df2[df2['offer'] == True]
Offered_By_List = list(schoolsOffered['team_name'])
```

**Output:**

```
print(df2.to_string())
    college_id  commit commit_date                                    commitments_url      id interest  offer recruiters   sign  site_id        site_name                                          team_logo         team_name visits
0           51    True  2020-04-27  //centralmichigan.rivals.com/commitments/footb...  779864     HIGH   True         []  False     21.0  centralmichigan  https://s.yimg.com/xe/ipt/CentralMichiganChipp...  Central Michigan     []
1           48   False        None                                               None  794033     NONE   True         []  False      NaN             None  https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/151102/akron-...             Akron     []
2           49   False        None                                               None  850677     NONE   True         []  False      NaN             None  https://s.yimg.com/cv/ae/default/170622/Ball-S...        Ball State     []
3           11   False        None  //bostoncollege.rivals.com/commitments/footbal...  817746     NONE   True         []  False     15.0    bostoncollege  https://s.yimg.com/xe/i/us/sp/v/ncaaf/teams/20...    Boston College     []
4           50   False        None                                               None  835972     NONE   True         []  False      NaN             None  https://s.yimg.com/xe/i/us/sp/v/ncaaf/teams/20...     Bowling Green     []
5          209   False        None                                               None  835973     NONE   True         []  False      NaN             None  https://sp.yimg.com/j/assets/ipt/BuffaloBulls.png           Buffalo     []
6           99   False        None  //cincinnati.rivals.com/commitments/football/2021  833595     NONE   True         []  False     23.0       cincinnati             https://s.yimg.com/xe/ipt/CINC_300.png        Cincinnati     []
7           28   False        None     //Indiana.rivals.com/commitments/football/2021  825797     NONE   True         []  False     51.0          Indiana  https://s.yimg.com/xe/i/us/sp/v/ncaaf/teams/20...           Indiana     []
8           20   False        None   //iowastate.rivals.com/commitments/football/2021  836116     NONE   True         []  False     55.0        iowastate  https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/151102/IowaSt...        Iowa State     []
9           53   False        None   //kentstate.rivals.com/commitments/football/2021  850678     NONE   True         []  False     62.0        kentstate  https://s.yimg.com/xe/i/us/sp/v/ncaaf/teams/20...        Kent State     []
10          54   False        None                                               None  850676     NONE   True         []  False      NaN             None  https://s.yimg.com/cv/ae/default/170623/Miami-...        Miami (OH)     []
11          15   False        None    //syracuse.rivals.com/commitments/football/2021  804815     NONE   True         []  False    133.0         syracuse  https://s.yimg.com/xe/i/us/sp/v/ncaaf/teams/20...          Syracuse     []
12          16   False        None      //temple.rivals.com/commitments/football/2021  826633     NONE   True         []  False    135.0           temple  https://s.yimg.com/xe/i/us/sp/v/ncaaf/teams/20...            Temple     []
13          56   False        None      //toledo.rivals.com/commitments/football/2021  783815     NONE   True         []  False    144.0           toledo  https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/160427/Toledo...            Toledo     []
14          57   False        None  //westernmichigan.rivals.com/commitments/footb...  783814     NONE   True         []  False    168.0  westernmichigan  https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/170213/wm_nca...  Western Michigan     []
15          27   False        None    //Illinois.rivals.com/commitments/football/2021  783816     NONE  False         []  False     49.0         Illinois         https://s.yimg.com/xe/ipt/illinois_300.png          Illinois     []
16          72   False        None   //Tennessee.rivals.com/commitments/football/2021  856404     NONE  False         []  False    136.0        Tennessee  https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/151102/Tennes...         Tennessee     []
17          63   False        None         //USC.rivals.com/commitments/football/2021  856403     NONE  False         []  False    151.0              USC  https://s.yimg.com/xe/i/us/sp/v/ncaaf/teams/20...               USC     []
```

And just the list:

```
print(Offered_By_List)
['Central Michigan', 'Akron', 'Ball State', 'Boston College', 'Bowling Green', 'Buffalo', 'Cincinnati', 'Indiana', 'Iowa State', 'Kent State', 'Miami (OH)', 'Syracuse', 'Temple', 'Toledo', 'Western Michigan']
```